# How can I install Armadillo on Windows?

Tags: xcode, visual-studio, ide, static-libraries, armadillo

I need to install and use `Armadillo` library to deal with **linear algebra**.

I went to their websites and downloaded `.tar.xz` file, but I have no idea how to install it.

How can I install `Armadillo`? (I'm primarily using `Dev-C++`, but I also sometimes use `XCode`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Windows, you might be using Visual Studio for compilation. Extract tarball using 7zip or other extraction software and save it in the directory of your choice. For example your path could be, `C:\armadillo`.

In the Visual Studio solution, do the following:

- Add armadillo directory under `Property Manager --> C/C++ --> General --> Additional Include Directories`, add semicolon after existing entries, followed by `C:\armadillo\include;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)`

If you are using 64-bit version to build also do the following:

- `Property Manager --> Linker --> General --> Additional Library Directories`, add semicolon after existing entries, followed by `C:\armadillo\examples\lib_win64;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)`
- `Property Manager --> Linker --> Input --> Additional Dependencies`, add semicolon after existing entries, followed by `blas_win64_MT.lib;lapack_win64_MT.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)`

Ensure that you are modifying the `Property Manager` in the same `Solution Configuration` and `Solution Platform` that you are using for the build. If this was successful, you should be able to use armadillo by simply adding `#include <armadillo>` in your header file.

Comment: Is the procedure the same for C++? I am using C++ and did everything you said. Now, I can define a matrix, e.g., `arma::Mat<double> A = arma::randu(4, 4);`, but I when I try to execute, for exampe `std::cout << A * A.t() << "\n";`, I get the error _The code execution cannot proceed because blas_win65_MT.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem._

Comment: @Antoine Yes these directions apply for using C++. Can you confirm that `blas_win64_MT.lib` and `blas_win64_MT.dll` files are in the directory you listed in the `Additional LIbrary Directories` ?

Comment: Yes, I can. At the end, I solved this issue by manually copying the `.dll` file into the folder where `.exe` appears.

Comment: @Antoine that should work too. But it's surprising that it can't find it outside of the `.exe` directory. One more thing to check would be whether the `Property Manager` is set to the right `Solution Configuration`. I've done this mistake before, where the `Solution` is set to `x86` and the properties were set to `x64`.

Comment: Also, you should copy `blas_win64_MT.dll` and `lapack_win64_MT.dll` from `armadillo\examples` to `project_name\x64\Debug(or Release)`

Answer (score 0):

.tar.xz is archive. Try using [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html) for extracting.

Answer (score 0):

Armadillo is a c++ library and does not need "installing". Just extract the archive and point your compiler/linker to the appropriate subfolders. For gcc the options are -L for the library path and -I for the include path. For finally running your program you would do something like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=[path to library folder of armadillo] ./[your program]` under linux, not sure what the corresponding command would be under windows.

Answer (score 0):

Its much easier to install and use Msys.

With Msys installed, open a terminal and type

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-armadillo
```