# Operating on slices of Cube in armadillo

Tags: c++, c++11, linear-algebra, armadillo

I am trying to get used to armadillo linear algebra library for c++ and I cannot figure out hot to operate on slices(matrices) of a cube. Whenever I try to operate on a slice, the program compiles but does not give any output, not even the outputs of statement before the slice operation.
Here's the code:

```
#include <armadillo>
#include <iostream>
using namespace arma;
using namespace std;

int main()
{

Cube<double> A(3  , 5 ,1, fill::randu);

Cube<double>B(5,3,1,fill::randu);
Mat<double>x  =A.slice(0);
Mat<double>y = B.slice(0);
cout << x << "\n" << y << endl;
cout << x*y << endl; //code works fine if this line is removed
}
```

the problem is that the code works fine if the last line is removed. Why does this happen? Is there a better way to operate on matrices inside a cube ?

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem, code works fine for me. Maybe related to armadillo or compiler version? I use armadillo 7.300 and gcc 6.2.1.

Comment: @Hannebambel I am using armadillo 7.950.1 and gcc 7.1.0 on windows 10

Comment: @Hannebambel are you using windows ?I think that might be the problem because armadillo libraries are built using MSVC 2012

Comment: I am using linux and just verified your program using Armadillo 7.900 and gcc 7.1.1 and also clang 4.0.0. So I guess you are right and Windows is the problem here. Maybe you can compile armadillo yourself using gcc?

Comment: @Hannebambel Well I am used to standard libraries and it is the first time I am using some external math library. So, I don't know how to build armadillo using gcc. Can you provide the steps or a link to some website that does ?

Comment: No, I am sorry, I have no experience programming on windows... Get the source of armadillo from their website and have a look at the readme. It seems to me that you only need to include the right directory for use with gcc. Try `-I/path/to/armadillo/include`. Maybe that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use directions given in the accepted answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44551414/how-can-i-install-armadillo-on-windows/44659049#44659049) question, to install Armadillo on Windows using Visual Studio.

If you have asked the Linker to use `blas_win64_MT.lib` and `lapack_win64_MT.lib` libraries, make sure to add the respective `.dll`'s in the same directory as your `.exe` file. Then using this code, I get the desired output.

```
#include <armadillo>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

int main()
{
    Cube<double> A(3, 5, 1, fill::randu);
    Cube<double> B(5, 3, 1, fill::randu);

    Mat<double> x = A.slice(0);
    Mat<double> y = B.slice(0);

    std::cout << "x:\n" << x << "\ny:\n" << y << std::endl;
    std::cout << "x*y:\n" << x*y << std::endl;
}
```

Output in command window:

[image: Armadillo Cube Demo]

Hope that helps!

Comment: I am using gcc compiler. Can't it be used to build armadillo in windows ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I use gcc on a Linux machine and VS on Windows machine. If you are using `Cygwin` in Windows to compile using `gcc`, instructions for compiling using `gcc` should work in Windows as well. The [documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html) says that: "BLAS is used for matrix multiplication. Without BLAS, Armadillo will use a built-in matrix multiplication routine.... ". Are you using OpenBLAS?

Comment: No . I have switched to ubuntu now . Everything works well .