# Integration of Armadillo in x86 C++ Application in Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, x86, 32bit-64bit, armadillo

since last week I'm working with the "Armadillo" C++-library.
I started with a default 64-bit C++ application in Microsoft Visual Studio. For the installation I followed the steps in the post below:

[How can I install Armadillo on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44551414/how-can-i-install-armadillo-on-windows)

Following these steps, everything worked fine for me.

But now I have to expand my C++-application and have to include/integrate another .dll. The problem for me is, that this .dll is a 32 bit .dll. So when I try to call it in my 64-bit application, which uses the Armadillo library, I always get the "class not registered"-error. This is why I want to migrate my whole project into a x86-application. But for some reason I'm not able to migrate the Armadillo-library into this x86-application (Following the instructions in the link above doesnt works anymore). While building the programm I always get more than 50 "LNK2019" errors.

Does anyone know how to fix the problem and know who to integrate Armadillo into a 32-bit application?

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: You need the 32-bit DLLs for the Armadillo library. LNK2019 suggests that you haven't properly added a reference to the library in your "Win32" build configuration (which is the one for 32-bit).

Comment: Ok thanks,I suspected something like this. Does anyone know where to get these 32-bit DLL, because the .zip of Armadillo only comes with the 64-bit-DLL/.lib? Or do I have to create the 32-bit-DLL on my own (Using cMake or something else). If yes, does anyone have a good tutorial/manual on doing so?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

For me it works with replacing the x64-bit "libopenblas.lib" and "libopenblas.dll", which are installed from Armadillo by default, with the x86 "libopenblas.lib" and "libopenblas.dll", which are included in the "OpenBLAS-0.3.15-x86.zip" download file from the OpenBlas release page on GitHub:

https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/releases

Probably it is enough to only replace the "libopenblas.lib" file.

Comment: It probably is *not* enough to replace only the .lib file. If you're dynamically linking a library, the .lib file contains "stubs" that the linker uses to insert calls to the functions exported by the DLL. The link step needs the .lib file, and then you require the .dll at runtime. (If you're not dynamically linking but statically linking, then you don't need the .dll at all, and the .lib file contains the complete implementation of the functions, which the linker links into your .exe.)

Comment: Oh thanks, good to know. I think: In my case I'm only linking statically.